# Meaning of attributes in Notepad++ autocompletion file?

Tags: ruby, notepad++

I want to create an autocomplete ruby.xml from a word list:

```
'to_a'  
'to_b'  
'to_c'
```

so i am able to call tips for long method's names. In notepad++ wiki page, the API completion seems cryptic with me. what are meanings of the following arguments? `ignoreCase,startFunc,stopFunc,paramSeparator, terminal,additionalWordChar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
<NotepadPlus>
   <AutoComplete language="ruby">
       <Environment **ignoreCase="no" startFunc="(" stopFunc=")" paramSeparator="," terminal=";" additionalWordChar = "."/**>
       <KeyWord name="**to_a**" func="yes">
           <Overload retVal="int" descr="Returns absolute value of given integer">
               <Param name="int number" />
           </Overload>
       </KeyWord>
   </AutoComplete>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

- ignorecase -- if no, then the function names are case-sensitive.
- startFunc  -- the character that appears just before the function's
  parameters.
- stopFunc   -- the character that indicates the end of the parameters.
- terminal   -- the character that ends a function definition.
- additionalWordChar -- a non-alpha-numeric character that can be part
  of a name.